# How can I set div width same as parent, when scroll appears?

Tags: html, css, scroll

## [Demo](http://codepen.io/mavlutovr/pen/oLJXzb?editors=1100#0)

## Html

When vertical scroll  appears, also horizontal scroll appears and elements in div are still wider then div  container. [Screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oqFid.png)

```
.scroll {
  overflow-y: auto;
  background: #CCC;
  display: inline-block;
  height: 150px;
}

.element {
  background: #CD8115;
}
```

## Css

```
<div class="scroll">
  <div class="list">
    <div class="element">111111111111111111111</div>
    <div class="element">22</div>
    ...
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Set the list css class with value display: inherit. This will make the child span then entire width.

```
.list{
 display: inherit;
}
```

```css
.scroll {
  overflow-y: auto;
  background: #CCC;
  display: inline-block;
  height: 150px;
}
.list{
  display: inherit;
}
.element {
  background: #CD8115;
}
```

```html
<h2>With scroll</h2>
<div class="scroll">
  <div class="list">
    <div class="element">111111111111111111111</div>
    <div class="element">22</div>
    <div class="element">333333333</div>
    <div class="element">4444</div>
    <div class="element">5555555</div>
    <div class="element">66</div>
    <div class="element">777</div>
    <div class="element">8888</div>
    <div class="element">99999</div>
    <div class="element">0</div>
  </div>
</div>

<!-- Absolt same, exept height: auto-->
<h2>Without scroll</h2>
<div class="scroll" style="height: auto;">
  <div class="list">
    <div class="element">111111111111111111111</div>
    <div class="element">22</div>
    <div class="element">333333333</div>
    <div class="element">4444</div>
    <div class="element">5555555</div>
    <div class="element">66</div>
    <div class="element">777</div>
    <div class="element">8888</div>
    <div class="element">99999</div>
    <div class="element">0</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: no, it's not work, see demo http://codepen.io/mavlutovr/pen/oLJXzb?editors=1100#0